# Facebook redirects to sign up page after authenticating user Rails

Tags: facebook, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, facebook-login

I am intergrating Facebook login using device, and after allowing Facebook to get your info it redirects you to the sign up page. Here's my code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
 before_action :authenticate_user!
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :description, :photo ])

 devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username, :first_name, :last_name, :description, :photo ])
end

end
```

Callback controller

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
 def facebook
  @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

if @user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw         if @user is not activated
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
else
  session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
 end

end

def failure
  redirect_to root_path
end
end
```

And my user model is

```
def self.new_with_session(params, session)
super.tap do |user|
  if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
    user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
  end
 end
end

 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
  user.email = auth.info.email
  user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
  user.first_name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
  user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
end
end
```

I'd really appreciate an extra eye on what I'm doing wrong, or where I am missing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this column for provider and uid to your users table, i think rails can't match your user :

```
rails g migration add_provider_and_uid_to_users provider:string uid: string
```

And try to write me the rails server response it Can help to figure out the bug source

Comment: I have the provider and uid in my user's table.